# Newly installed Eclipse and Android SDK. Can't get emulator to work. Hangs on clock screen

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm brand new to development.

I've installed Eclipse and Andoid SDK. But, I can't get emulator to work. I've tried the sample notepad code and Hello Android tutorial code. Each time I try to run either app it just hangs on clock screen (screen also says charging 50% and has a padlock).

Here is the console info for the sample notepad app.

```
[2011-03-11 15:27:17 - samplenotpad] ------------------------------
[2011-03-11 15:27:17 - samplenotpad] Android Launch!
[2011-03-11 15:27:17 - samplenotpad] adb is running normally.
[2011-03-11 15:27:17 - samplenotpad] Performing com.example.android.notepad.NotesList activity launch
[2011-03-11 15:27:17 - samplenotpad] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'myEmulator3'
[2011-03-11 15:27:17 - samplenotpad] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'myEmulator3'
[2011-03-11 15:27:19 - samplenotpad] New emulator found: emulator-5556
[2011-03-11 15:27:19 - samplenotpad] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-03-11 15:27:33 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentred
[2011-03-11 15:27:33 - Emulator] 
[2011-03-11 15:28:17 - samplenotpad] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5556'
[2011-03-11 15:28:17 - samplenotpad] Uploading samplenotpad.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2011-03-11 15:28:17 - samplenotpad] Installing samplenotpad.apk...
[2011-03-11 15:29:09 - samplenotpad] Success!
[2011-03-11 15:29:10 - samplenotpad] Starting activity com.example.android.notepad.NotesList on device emulator-5556
```

Then nothing...

---

I've tried the following steps already from this page, but still not working.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/troubleshooting.html#eclipse

Eclipse isn't talking to the emulator

When communication doesn't seem to be happening between Eclipse and the emulator, symptoms can include: nothing happening when you press run, the emulator hanging waiting for a debugger to connect, or errors that Eclipse reports about not being able to find the emulator or shell. By far the most common symptom is that when you press run, the emulator starts (or is already running), but the application doesn't start.

You may find any of these steps will fix the problem and with practice you probably can figure out which one you need to do for your particular issue, but to start with, the safest option is to run through all of them in order:

- Quit the emulator if it is running
- Check that any emulator processes are killed (sometimes they can hang, use
  ps on unix or mac, or task manager in the process view on windows).
- Quit Eclipse From the command line, type: adb kill-server, start Eclipse and try again

---

Wondering if I need to try uninstalling and reinstalling some component?

I'm running Windows 7.

Any help much appreciated - in as plain english language as possible please :-)

Comment: Try closing everything , i.e. eclipse , emulator , adb and make sure its not running. Then start over again. with starting adb server , and check whether your emulator is connected using adb devices,  launch eclipse and run.

Comment: What's your hardware spec?  The emulator is extremely slow, and doesn't work at all on low end machines. It's just about acceptable on my Phenom 2 @2.66GHz, but on the old P4 I got it to replace it just crashed on startup every time.

Answer (score 14):

Are you at the unlock screen?  Did you unlock the "phone"  You need to drag the unlock button with your mouse by clicking on the button and then dragging to the right

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to development pls try the following step

1. Restart Eclipse
2. Open the Android SDK and AVD Manager
3. Delete your existing AVD
4. Recreate the AVD with your set of paramaters (i.e. name, android version etc)
5. Go back to your code and run the program again.

You should now be able to run the sample programs again..

Hope it helps

Bob

Comment: It does not help Bob.

Answer (score 1):

Setting eclipse, adb and emulator to high priority (it wouldn't let me set it to real time), restarting eclipse, and deleting the emulator and creating a new one actually made the emulator start working for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the power button once (it's on the right side). Now try to drag the unlock button on the screen and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the ,memory resources are inadequate for running emulator. One thing you can do is that when the emulator hangs for the first time, just close it and then restart it. After this go to Task Manager and set the emulator and adb priority to real time.

Comment: Hi - thanks for responses. Its returning "device" using adb devices so seems to be connected. When I try to change the emulator priority in task manager it says access denied. Any other suggestions? Or, how to get around the access denied issue?

Comment: Access denied comes when you dont have the Admin privileges or you can say that when your login account in windows does not falls in the Admin group. Please coordinate with your network eng. to get admin privileges

Comment: Thanks rohit. I am the only user of my computer and I have admin privileges which is why I couldn't understand it. After googling around, I was able to stop the access denied message by first clicking on "show processes from all users" in task manager. If I don't click that first, it will sometimes give me the access denied message, sometimes change it, and sometimes say can't change to realtime so will change to priority high instead. I have no idea what is up with windows, but am putting this info here in case anyone else strikes same problem.Emulator is working better now but still not well

Comment: I'm using a Sony Vaio Z series laptop with 4GB ram. Its only 6 months old and a high end laptop, so I'm not sure why it can't cope with running the emulator. When I click on buttons in the emulator, its sometimes non responsive, but at least sometimes working now.

Comment: How I can do it under Win 8?