# Cannot get Android Emulator to start

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator

I understand there are many threads like mine but I have been trying to get an Android Emulator to work on my Windows XP PC and have encountered nothing but brickwalls. Here is what I've done:

- I installed the latest JDK (Version 6 Revision 26) ... no problem
- I unpacked "Eclipse" (Version 3.7 - Indigo) ... no problem
- I downloaded and unzipped Android SDK ... no problem
- I updated Android SDK with Android SDK Tools and two platforms (2.2 and 3.1) ... no problem
- I installed the ADT plug-in for Eclipse ... no problem
- I configured ADT to point to the Android SDK ... no problems
- I created the "Hello World" app from the Android developers site ... no problem
- I tried to run it...

And this is where I've been halted. I've tried:

- Creating an AVD with default settings in both 3.1 and 2.2 ... no luck
- Changing device RAM size ... no luck
- Starting the AVD from Android SDK ... no luck
- Starting AVD from the command line ... no luck
- Starting it with no animation ... no luck
- Leaving it to start over night, twice, with different settings ... no luck

I've been perusing websites for hours trying to find other solutions but having absolutely no luck?!?

It basically starts to load, it shows the "A N D R O I D _" animation and then moves to the one where the green "swoosh" moves across the logo and then it just sits there...for hours! If I try and run the "Hello World" app while it's in this state it just fails (obviously.) I don't know if I'm missing something obvious or what?!? I'm happy to uninstall everything and try again but not before I've exhausted reasonable measures to fix what I imagine to be an easy problem to solve?!?

Comment: Have you tried going to the menu from the control panel (i.e. the silver control panel that appears next to the emulator screen)? I found that AVD wouldn't always launch my app directly into the emulator, but I could navigate to my app through the menu system and launch it from there. It might also help if you post a screenshot of what you're seeing.

Comment: The problem was that the emulator hadn't fnished loading so the app would fail when I tried to launch it, but it appears UIDreamer's solution below worked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this process.

1. Close your Eclipse IDE
2. Restart the IDE and delete the AVD created.
3. Create the AVD and then relaunch the application.

Please let me know if this process helped you.
Similar issue here:
[Newly installed Eclipse and Android SDK. Can't get emulator to work. Hangs on clock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268396/newly-installed-eclipse-and-android-sdk-cant-get-emulator-to-work-hangs-on-clo)

Comment: Thanks for this UIDreamer. While I had tried this I believe the combination of a few factors helped in my eventual solution. I found a suggestion somewhere (which I can't find again unfortunately) that I've incorporated into the rebuild of the AVD, this is what I did:
 - Renamed the AVD without numbers i.e. "mytest"
 - Ensured I enabled "snapshot"
 - Added the "Device RAM size" attribute (set to only 256)
And it appears to now work. Thanks a million :-)

Answer (score 1):

Create an APK file (archive for java app for Android), copy to the machine using usb cable or whatever you use, and then just install it. Not the ideal, but it helps.